# How to parse for a number greater than x in a file

Tags: powershell

Powershell newbie here, just started to play around with it last month.  I've been trying to figure out ways to use it and right now I'm trying to pull information from some of our unix servers and am having a difficult time parsing the data to get what I need.  Basically, I'm running an ssh command to pull the # of closed_waits on a server and outputting it to a file with the server name delimited by a comma.  So my output looks like this:

```
2,<server1>
3,<server2>
3,<server3>
```

etc...  there are around 70 servers in the list.  I want to be able to look at the first column (the #) and for any one that is over a specific number, say 250, and output that with the server name.  I've been able to split the line and search on just the #, but can't figure out how to just search on the # without pulling it out so I can output the server name along with it.

my last attempt, which still doesn't work went something like this:

```
get-content "cresultsf.txt" | %{$close = $_.split(","} | where-object {$_.$close[0] -gt 250}
```

Picked PS scripting up last month so I'm VERY new at this.  I've probably read through 100 articles today trying to put this together so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a try as following:

text.txt:

```
1, server1
200, server2
1, server3
400, server4
15, server5
119, server6
120, server7
300, server8
290, server9
```

my commands:

```
$data = import-csv -path .\test.txt -header close, server
$data | where-object{$_.close -gt 250} |format-table -autosize
```

and the output is:

```
close server
----- ------
400   server4
300   server8
290   server9
```

Comment: That worked great!! Thank you very much!  I saw the import-csv option when I was looking through articles but hadn't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Requires V3:

```
get-content "cresultsf.txt" | %{
 [PSCustomObject]@{
               $split = $_.split(',')
               Close = [int]$split[0]
               Server = $split[1]
               }
 } | where { $_.close -gt 250 }
```

Powershell is all about objects, so it's usually easier if you create and then work with objects.
The [PSCustomObject] type accelerator lets you create an object directly from a hash table.  Since you're reading text data from a file, all of the values will be [string].  The Close property is explicity case to [int] to prevent unexpected results when you do the comparison.